# sql query cannot create table with auto calculated column

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhZmz.jpg)Dear all coder please help me with this. I am unable to create table in sql server 2008, can any one help me with this please. Trust me I am coming here after beating my head all over. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STransactions](
    [ATId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ADeposit] [int] NULL,
    [ACredit] [int] NULL,
    [ABalance]  AS sum([ADeposit]-[ACredit])
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `sum()` for that; just subtraction.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STransactions](
    [ATId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ADeposit] [int] NULL,
    [ACredit] [int] NULL,
    [ABalance]  AS ([ADeposit]-[ACredit])
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

For a view with an running balance like your picture:

```
create view dbo.STransactions_wBalance as 
  select
      t.AtID
    , t.ItemId
    , t.ADeposit
    , t.ACredit
    , x.Balance
  from dbo.STransactions t
    cross apply (
    select Balance = sum(ADeposit-ACredit)
    from dbo.STransactions as i
    where i.ItemId = t.ItemId
      and i.AtID  <= t.AtID
    ) x;
go
```

Then query the view instead of the table.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply but it doesn't meet my requirement. What I want is in each row for each transaction the balance should be automatically calculated, for the total of Debit - Credit in every row I insert, It should not be Debit - Credit for the single row but for the entire previous row. I have attached the picture, could you please guide me further.. Sorry if I am unable to make you understand.

Comment: @DharamRai Ahh I see.... You can't do that in-line like that. You could create a function and use that function for your calculated column -- but that is not a good idea. You would not be able to persist or index it anyway. I would suggest creating a `view` that satisfies your criteria instead of a computed column.

Comment: Could you please donate me how to do that, I haven't done any :(

Comment: @DharamRai Updated my answer with the sql to create a view based on your picture.

Comment: I am trying but getting an error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure STransactions_wBalance, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'rows'.

Comment: @DharamRai Updated with a sql server 2008 compatible version.

Comment: Okay now view got created but since I am new to it, Idont know how it works I tried entering data on it by edit mood but did not change the value in the Balance column, or is there other way to test if?

Comment: @DharamRai If you wanted `balance` to be a calculated column, why do you now want to edit it? That doesn't make any sense to me. You would `insert` rows into the `dbo.STransactions` table, and when you want to see the `balance` then you would `select` from the view.

Comment: oh okay, sorry cause I am new to it must be bothering you a lot. Thanks for all the help. One last question can I create store procedure with view and call in my rdlc report?

Comment: @DharamRai Yes, you can create a stored procedure to query the view and use the procedure in the rdlc report.